# Undefined result returned from cURL GET request

Tags: php, curl, reverse-proxy, php-curl

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy between my html frontend, and backend microservices.

Without the proxy server, the code works fine.

Text is input to the frontend, its sent via XMLrequest to the php proxy on button click, then a get request is made by cURL to python backend microservice. I think my problem is the sending of the get request with the input text. The result returned is undefined because there is a problem with sending the input text.
My frontend returns, "undefined" - so at least I know they are connected.

I am running the code on my local host, before later dockerising the application

If anyone has any pointers, it would be greatly appreciated!

**FRONTEND**

```
function Check_1() //total
{
    
     input_text = document.getElementById('input-text').value;
       
       
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var j = JSON.parse(this.response);
               total_marks = j.answer;
                
                displayTotal(total_marks);
                
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET",proxyURL+"?input_text="+"/");
        xhttp.send();

        return;
    }

 <div>
        <button class="sgcbutton-active" onclick="Check_1();">Total Marks</button>
    </div>
```

**PROXY**

```
<?php


header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type: application/json");

$output = array(
    "error" => false,
  "string" => "",
    "answer" => 0
);

$SITE_NAME_1 = "http://localhost:90"; 

$input_text = $_REQUEST['input_text'];


$URL = $SITE_NAME_1."/?input_text=".$input_text;



//curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


echo ($result);
exit();
```

**Python BACKEND**

```
import function
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np 

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
     #inputtext = request.args.get('input_text')
     input_text = stringinput()
     theanswer = function.checkArray(input_text)

     x = {
      "error": 'false',
      "string": "",
      "answer": theanswer
     }
     
     reply = json.dumps(x)
     r = Response (response=reply, status=200)
     r.headers["Content-Type"]="application/json"
     r.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]="*"
     return r


@app.route("/", methods=['GET']) 
def stringinput():
     inputtext = request.args.get('input_text')
     return inputtext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

NOTE

I believe the communication between all three pages is fine - status code 200

Comment: If this is new code you should be using `fetch()`, not the archaic `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `json_encode($result)` in the proxy. You already encoded as JSON in the backend, so `$result` is JSON.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out! I made those changes, but no luck. I think the problem lies in making the cURL get request to the php backend. The URL isn't concatenated correctly? I'm not sure

Comment: That's also possible, I assumed you've already ensured that the URL is correct.

Comment: BTW, your loop in the JS looks like it's just emulating `input_text_edited = lines.join("newline");`

Comment: Why do you need `else if (document.getElementById('input-text').value.length==0)`? Isn't that the same as the previous condition `else if (input_text = '')`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ethry - Hopefully that's a bit clearer to understand now

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the problem but when you put the URL in the curl_init, you do not need `CURLOPT_URL` in the `setopt`.

You do not show what the URL looks like. That could be an issue.
You may have to use `urlencode()` or  `rawurlencode()` I prefer using POST requests to avoid urlencode.

You need to look at the outgoing request header. 
For that you need this setopt:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

It's usually a good idea to build the request header, including the host.
You can make the header look just like your Browser

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,* / *;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";

$ch = curl_init($url);
```

You should use this setopt also:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

The first two setopts are needed if the request is HTTPS
I've been using this code for over ten years.  
I just used it last weekend to scrape Zillow to get listings.
I'm confident this will help you find the problem. 
I am assuming the URL works in a Browser.
You could get the Raw Request heder from you Browser. Sometimes that urlencoding can get tricky.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
var_export(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo  curl_error($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I really appreciate your help!
I'll give that a go and hopefully I can make mine work!